# Line numbers in jtextpane in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, netbeans-7, line-numbers

I am using Netbeans 7.1.  are there any option for displaying line numbers in jtextpane?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try using [Text Component Line Number](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/23/text-component-line-number/).

Comment: Please do tell me is this you who wrote that blog. +1 for the info though, I just read that blog, as I came to this question.  Regards